# Using Attributes End With to delete elements

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector

I have been trying to implement the attributeEndsWith selector to delete multiple elements with Ids ending with "_vb ("[id$="_vb"]"). Unfortiunately the code I have below doesnt work. Can someone help me to correct this code please?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var elem = document.getElementById('div[id$="_vb"]');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) doesn't work like that, you want the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function ([`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div[id$="_vb"]').remove();
   return false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/